# Document Editing on Web Server

Tags: asp.net, apache, microsoft-exchange, webdav, microsoft-office

All,

I will be creating a website that basically hosts/organizes various microsoft type files such as docx, xlsx, etc. I am only familiar with apache and php based web servers but my work is more familiar with IIS. So after digging around I started to realize maybe that is a good thing because IIS should have the .net framework support on the backend for a way to edit or open these document types. So I have been digging around and typically what I have found is people trying to embed word processors and things of that nature in their site. Well what I want to do is allow users to open these documents in their actual microsoft word, excel, etc programs but let them save them back to the web server. Is something like this even possible with IIS and .net framework? If so, could you point me in the right direction of how I could achieve this?

Having not been familiar with C# is it possible to do this on an APACHE server with php rather than c#?

Comment: Local editors can only edit loal files, as you would expect (unless they provide native remote capabilities,like FTP). You'll need to download the file first, edit in Word, and upload it again. Not the job of a webserver certainly, either IIS or Apache or anything else. You may try to look for an Office plugin that support this foryour site tech.

Comment: If WebDAV was enabled on the IIS server and Stores the files. Then if website points to the files stored there for all links then would this accomplish this?

Comment: If you expose the files on WebDAV and use Windows Explorer to map it as a drive, then no program would ever notice the difference, and even Office programs would simply read/write to it. Yes, it could work, sounds like a good approach to me.

Comment: This server is only accessible from inside network/vpn but I did not think I needed to map the drive for users accessing the site. Is this a requirement to make site links on website load in office by default? I had read of using this for links ms-word:ofe|u| and it forces program to open in word, etc but it just requires a WebDav and some other settings to be enabled. Guess I’ll give this a try and fingers crossed WebDav stays supported my Microsoft!

Comment: WebDAV lacks supports in almost every program out there, but Windows Explorer has rudimentary support for it, though drive letter mapping. When you map a WebDAV to a drive, programs simply access it as if it was local, unaware of the real nature of the data storage, Windows Explorer does the download/upload in backgroud. But given that t he server is in the LAN, why not simply use normal file shares that Windows natively support? I don't think you need anything else over them given that fact.

Comment: When you develop a website and included a link/href to a file it will download it from my understanding and not actually open the file from that directory. However, I read that a website(although hosted only for local access in my scenario) can link/href a webdav file path and force the client pc it to open with microsoft office products if they are installed. Unless I am mistaken. My colleagues are persistant to still use word products for live editing while I am only familiar with web development so this is why I was asking about this route.

Comment: A normal website yes, you download and that's all, you have a local copy that you must reupload somehow afterwards. WebDAV is just exposing shares over a web server (Apache/IIS/whatever) so that programs "think" it's local while it's actually remote. You can use such options for contining using normal Office programs.

Comment: My research has shown WebDAV is very buggy. Is there any other options to accomplish users being able to edit word documents on a website without the huge price tag of a online word processor(ie syncfusion). We are a Microsoft based organization so we do have a SharePoint server hosted locally I believe which I could save and access the files to from.